# How to get all Posts from Communities that User has joined in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a User model, Community model, Post model and UserJoinedCommunity model. What I want to do is get all Posts from Communities that User has joined so I can display them on home page.

UserJoinedCommunity model that controlls which user has joined which community:

```py
class UserJoinedCommunity(models.Model):
    """DB Model for users joined communities"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'community'], name="user-joined-community")
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}|{self.community.name}"
```

`Community` and `Post` models are just simple models with fields like name, title etc.

So now I would like to create a APIView or ViewSet that would return all posts from communities that user has joined.

Something like this:

```py
class UserRelevantPosts(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request):
        user_relevant_posts = "?"
        return Response({'posts': user_relevant_posts}, status=200)
```

Tell me if you need more code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Community has a ManyToMany field of Post.
If not, I recommend adding it

```
class Comunity(models.Model):
    # some fields
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post)
```

```
from models import UserJoinedCommunity
class UserRelevantPosts(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.data['user'] # you receive the id of user
        user_relevant_posts = {} # dict to return
        # str(item.community) We pass the community name as a key
        # str is to convert it to string
        for item in UserJoinedCommunity.objects.filter(user=user).all():
            user_relevant_posts[str(item.community)] = item.community.post.all().values() 
        return Response({'posts': user_relevant_posts}, status=200)
```

The output of this is:

```
{
    "post": {
        "community1": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "post1"
            }
        ],
        "community2": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "post2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "post3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this ManyToMany field, it will solve more of my problems. Thanks!